# C exercise return information about first position

Tags: c, clion

exercise in C:
write a function 'any' wchich returns information about position of first occurrence in s1 any lsign from s2. Return -1 when s1 doesnt includes signs from s2.
And my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int any(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int i, j;
    int koniec;
    for (i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[j] == s2[i]) {
                koniec = j;
            }
            else
                {
                    koniec = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    return koniec;
    }



int main()
{
    char w1[] = "Dominik";
    char w2[] = "zcki";
    int wynik;
    wynik = any(w1, w2);
    printf("%d", wynik);
    return 0;

}
```

but it returns: -1
but should 3
what is wrong?

Comment: nevermind, it was enough to put: break; after koniec = j

Comment: Once you find a match you need to return the location. But you keep going and overwrite `koniec`.

Comment: `man strchr` ...

Answer (score 1):

Just `return` the position when you find it and do not keep looping:

```
int any(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[i] == s2[j]) {
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement within the inner loop

```
        if (s1[j] == s2[i]) {
            koniec = j;
        }
        else
            {
                koniec = -1;
            }
```

Does not make a sense because the value of the variable `koniec` will be overwritten in the last iterations of the both loops.

Moreover due to the order of the loops you are searching in fact a character from the string `s2` in the string `s1` while you need to find the first character in s1 that is present in s2.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

ptrdiff_t any( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    ptrdiff_t pos = -1;
    
    for ( const char *p1 = s1; pos == -1 && *p1; ++p1 )
    {
        const char *p2 = s2;
        while ( *p2 && *p2 != *p1 ) ++ p2;
        
        if ( *p2 ) pos = p1 - s1;
    }
    
    return pos;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char w1[] = "Dominik";
    char w2[] = "zcki"; 
    
    printf( "%td\n", any( w1, w2 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

Indeed the first character from `w1` that is present in `w2` is the character `'i'`.  Pay attention to that positions start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int any(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  int koniec=0;
  int j=0;
  for (int i = 0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {j=0;
      while(s1[i]!=s2[j]&&s2[j]!='\0')
      {
            j++;

      }
      if(s2[j]!='\0')
      {
          return j;
      }
  }
  return -1;
}


int main()
{
   char w1[] = "Dominik";
   char w2[] = "zcki";
   printf("%d\n", any(w1, w2));
   return 0;
}
```